# How can I restrict for unique values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Sample XML:

schema validation should be failed:

```
<Root>
  <A>0</A>
  <B>0</B>
  <C>2</C>
</Root>
```

schema validation should be passed:

```
<Root>
  <A>0</A>
  <B>1</B>
  <C>2</C>
</Root>
```

As shown in example there can be different elements viz. A, B, C... All the child elements will be of string type. I want to ensure that all the child elements are having unique values. For example A and B should not have same value. No child element should have same value. XSD should restrict it.

I tried with Unique but it checks for single element. not for different elements.

Comment: I think that you could use XSD 1.1 using assert feature. [See this link](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html)

Comment: Can I achieve same thig using XSD v1.0?